# noise and echo in QuickBlox VideoChat Sample

Tags: quickblox

I have installed the videochat sample (http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android) on my android smartphones and it launches perfectly.
But after clicking on either "Audio Call" or "Video Call", I get a lot of noise and echo in addiction to the audio/video delay.
Why is that so?

Comment: The call quality depends on the devices used, distance between devices, Internet connection etc.
Unfortunately currently there is no possibility to manage sound quality though you can manage video call quality:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android#Manage_call_quality
Which video quality did you use in your tests? Try to set low/medium video quality and check with these settings.